# Creating new epaper library for atmega32 without arduino

Tags: c, avr, spi

i want to create new library for my e-paper using atmega32 and eclipse enviroment. What do i have to know about it moreover how it works. I dont want to use arduino libraries, want to write it on my own. How to best start making it? I know how to use SPI, what commands do i have to send to display, but do i have to have any drivers which are necessarily? Is any possibilty to program it using only this module:
https://www.waveshare.com/1.54inch-e-paper-module-b.htm
and SPI? Or it is necessary to have some drivers to do it?

Comment: You need to study the specific MCU in detail. Start by reading all relevant application notes published by Atmel for the specific part. Not sure why anyone would voluntarily want to use Eclipse, but otherwise Atmel Studio should come with example code for basic startup and simple things like flashing LEDs. Same with commercial toolchains like Crossworks or IAR. Not sure what you mean with "to have any drivers", do you mean in the MCU or in the PC? You'll want some in circuit debugger to connect to the MCU.

Comment: Anyway, "how do I do my whole project" questions aren't the best fit for SO since they are very broad.

Answer (score 0):

Your question a little bit strange, because "driver" is usually piece of code, written by a third person. So, answer is yes - it is always possible to do it from scratch, without using third-side software.

First what you need to know is what type of controller being used in that display, to get technical documentation (datasheet). Unfortunately, there is no such information, but there is a link to the specification document: https://www.waveshare.com/w/upload/9/9e/1.54inch-e-paper-b-specification.pdf

Read it carefully. For example at page 8 you can find the list of commands, which are used to control the display, and below the detailed description of the commands.

At pages 24, 25 you can find initialization sequence, and reference flowchart.

If any doubts, you can download and investigate how third-party libraries are done. For example here: https://github.com/waveshare/e-Paper